# Is it possible to have javascript decorators (e.g. redux's @connect ) alongside ESbuild-loader

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-redux, esbuild

I'm using Webpack5 with ESbuild-loader for my React project's build pipeline.
For connecting my components to Redux store I use `@connect` decorator instead of using the HOC approach.

Example: `MyComponent.jsx`

```
@connect((state) => ({
    notes: state.notes,
}))
class MyComponent extends PureComponent {
    static propTypes = {
        notes: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.object),
    };
...
}
```

And here's my Webpack config rule for `js/jsx` files:

```
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules)/,
            loader: 'esbuild-loader',
            options: {
                loader: 'jsx',
                target: 'es2015',
            },
        },
```

When I try to start my dev server I get this error which is related to the line decorator is defined:

```
ERROR in ./project/MyComponent.jsx
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/esbuild-loader/dist/index.js):
Error: Transform failed with 1 error:
MyComponent.js:63:0: ERROR: Unexpected "@"
```

Does ESbuild not understand decorators?

Answer (score 1):

[According to library maintainer](https://github.com/privatenumber/esbuild-loader/issues/238), this is not possible yet.

> neither esbuild or esbuild-loader is advertised to support decorators.

Follow the discussion about future support [here](https://github.com/evanw/esbuild/issues/104).